# Exceeded List items comes in same line

Tags: html, css

I have creating list items like

```
<ul class="list">
<li>A</li>
...
...
<li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

Css is

```
.list
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
height: 42px;
clear: left;
width: 100%;
}
.list li
{
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

After ending of page. that is for example, A to M comes in same line, remaining Letters N to Z comes to next line. But it is in hidden.

I want A to Z comes on same line. but after M, Characters will be hidden.

Comment: Try giving `height: 42px;` to your lis as well. Since the parent has `overflow: hidden`, that should do it.

Comment: No same thing happen

Comment: Why do you want this? what is your purpose? I'm sure that there's a better alternative.

Comment: It has some functionality. So i need that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of floating your `li`s to the left, you should make them `display:inline` so that they still respect the layout rules of the `ul`.

```css
.list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.list li {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
    <ul class="list"><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li><li>G</li><li>H</li><li>I</li><li>J</li><li>K</li><li>L</li><li>M</li><li>N</li><li>O</li><li>P</li><li>Q</li><li>R</li><li>S</li><li>T</li><li>U</li><li>V</li><li>W</li><li>X</li><li>Y</li><li>Z</li></ul>
</div>
```